# How to delete data from an uninstalled app?

Tags: storage

My Android 8.0 phone is showing the 32 GB is full. I have deleted videos and stuff but I wonder if apps that I uninstalled have not deleted their data.
How to find out?

Answer (score 2):

For apps you have installed you should have some sort of app manager to view the app info --> storage, which you should probably clear data/cache before uninstalling.  Supposedly you could re-install an app and clear the data.

Alternatively install an app to help you clean up junk like "SD MAID" and use its CorpseFinder to find orphaned files, you get a list so you can go through and choose which files you want or not want and bin them I believe.

I've personally used ES File Explorer, which is better, but apparently it only seems to be available from 3rd party websites now as Google has removed it from the play store for "click fraud".